# Updated to Ubuntu 20.04 -now the Super key (win) is not working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 20.04

I just updated to 20.04 from 18.0.4 on my MSI CX62-7QL laptop, I'm using the Spanish (Win keys) layout and every single key is working *but* the Super or Win key. When I open the layout screen at *Setting > Region & Language > Input Sources* and I press the Win key to see if at least it's being recognized, it doesn't change to the grey tone that appears when you press the respective key. Oddly enough, if I press *Super+a* I can see the activities view.

The Win key **does work** when I'm using a different language layout and i'ts recognized on the layout scheme. The problem is, I can't stick to another layout because tildes the like get mangled up.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the super key works only on the FIRST keyboard layout under Settings/Input sources. So I just dragged 'en' to be the first one.

Comment: Although this might be solution for OP the first step would be to post a comment asking them what their current settings are.

Comment: Thank you Tin, that solved the problem. But I'm left wondering... why? What's the logic behind it?

Comment: It's simply a bug I'd guess. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug under Gnome, it only affects keyboard layouts in this order, so i know it isn't a permanent solution but you could switch your layouts into different order.

1. The super key will work
2. won't work
3. Won't Work
4. The super key will work again

Here is the [Bug already reported](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1144)